# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int S_n (x) f(x) dx = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the problem: Let $E = \bigcup_{m} [2m, 2m+1)$, Let $P(x) = \chi_{E} - \chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}$ (so that $P(x)$ is $1$ if the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ is even and is $−1$ if it is odd) and $S_n (x) =  P(10^{n}\cdot x)$
and prove that for every $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int S_n (x) f(x) dx = 0 $$.

Here's my effort: the statement can be simply proved for $\chi_{I}$ where $I$ is a bounded interval, then the statement is proved for $\chi_{F}$ for any measurable set $F$ by regularity of Lebesgue measure, then simple functions. But then I fail to generalize it to general $f$. Basically what bothers me here is I need to take 2 limit simultaneously, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Seems like $P(x)$ does not appear in the limit you want to compute, is there a typo somewhere ?

Comment: Oh sorry I just fixed it! $P$ is used to define $S$.

Comment: use the triangle inequality three times

Answer (score 3):

Here is a *standard machinery* for proving this type of problem.

First, we define the linear functional $T_n : L^1(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ T_n(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} S_n(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Then it is easy to check that $T_n$ is a bounded (hence continuous) linear functional:

$$ |T_n(f)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d}x = \| f\|_{L^1}$$

With this setting, the problem is rephrased as the question about whether $T_n(f) \to 0$ for all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. To this end, we invoke the following general result:

> **Theorem.** Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be normed spaces. Also, let $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ with uniformly bounded operator norm:
> $$ M := \sup_{n\geq 1}\sup_{\substack{x\in X \\ \|x\|_X = 1}} \|T_n(x)\|_Y < \infty $$
> If $D \subseteq X$ is a dense subset and $T_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x \in D$, then $T_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x \in X$.

(Or, stating this theorem in less functional-theoretic flavor, it tells that if a sequence of uniformly equicontinuous functions converges to $0$ on a space $D$, then it converges to $0$ uniformly on the *completion* $\overline{D}$ of $D$.)

Now applying this theorem with $X = L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $Y = \mathbb{R}$, and $D$ the space of compactly supported step functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (which is basically the linear span of the set of indicator functions of bounded intervals), it follows that $T_n(f) \to 0$ for *all* $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Hence the desired result follows.

---

*Proof of Theorem.* Let $M$ be the smallest uniform bound on the operator norms of $(T_n)$ as in the theorem. Let $x \in X$ and $x' \in D$. Then

\begin{align*}
\|T_n(x)\|_Y
&\leq \|T_n(x - x')\|_Y + \|T_n(x')\|_Y \\
&\leq M \|x - x'\|_X + \|T_n(x')\|_Y.
\end{align*}

Hence, taking $\limsup$ as $n \to \infty$, we get

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \|T_n(x)\|_Y \leq M \|x - x'\|_X. $$

Since the left-hand side is independent of the choice of $x' \in D$ and $D$ is dense in $X$, letting $x' \to x$ shows that

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \|T_n(x)\|_Y = 0, $$

which then proves that $T_n(x) \to 0$ in $Y$ as required. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

You said you've been able to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)\psi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$

whenever $\psi\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is simple. Take now any $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. Find a simple $\psi\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert\psi(x)-f(x)\rvert\,\mathbb{d}x<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

(using that the simple functions are dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$) and find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)\psi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

for all $n\geq N$. Then, for all $n\geq N$,

\begin{align*}
\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert
&\leq\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert+\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)(\psi(x)-f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert \\
&\leq\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert S_n(x)\rvert\lvert\psi(x)-f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq\underbrace{\left\lvert\int_{\mathbb{R}}S_n(x)\psi(x)\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert}_{<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}+\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lvert\psi(x)-f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x}_{<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}} \\
<\varepsilon.
\end{align*}